# Is there a way to create a sharepoint document library view using an IF statement that uses metadata?

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am trying to create a view from a sharepoint server 2016 document library that goes IF((criteria A = "X" AND criteria B= "Y"), show documents under criteria C).

Some documents in the library have a value for criteria A & B, but all documents have a value for Criteria C.

Word documents have a REVIEWER NAME & STATUS plus Title. PDF documents only have TITLE (same TITLE as word docs). I want to show a view that if (Word Document Reviewer = Reviewer X AND Word Document Status = Status Y), it will show all documents with the same TITLE (word docs & pdfs). There can be many pdf documents associated to a single title, but only one word document to that same title. Therefore, I'm trying to reduce how much metadata I have to fill out by only attached reviewer and status to the word document.

Any help is much appreciated. Or if it is not possible, knowing that would be nice too.

Thank you,
M

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using view filters. An option could be to use a calculated column (that allows you to write IF-Else Formulas where you can write nested if-else statements put a particular value in the column if match is found But i don't think you can go with this approach for title matching.

> Possible Solution:

To achieve what you want, you can create a workflow/power automate flow where you can find the word documents (doc or docx) based on your criteria i.e.

```
criteria A = "X" AND criteria B= "Y" AND Title ="[Current  Item Title]"
```

if a word document with same title is found you can populate a column e.g. `associated document id` with the the `ID` of matched word document. This will create a sort of logical grouping. Then you can filter your list view based on `associated document id` column or group items by  `associated document id` to show these together.